# How to add class to an element if another div width reach its position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck in something and need your help, i have been trying to figure out a `javascript` function but i am unable to get it with easy and light weight formula for a `cms` use.

I have a progress bar of the song. and below the progress bar there is a strip which contains images and those images have a hover effect as well, i want if the above progress reaches to anyone the image position in the below strip it ads and active class to the image and removes the class right after it passes the end of the image. Please check fiddle for working player.

```css
#containment-wrapper2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #aaa;
}

#progress {
  background: #000;
  height: 30px;
}

#containment-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #eee;
}

.comment {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}

.comment:hover,
.comment.active {
  background: red;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="containment-wrapper2">
  <div id="progress" style="width:41.2%;"></div>
</div>


<div id="containment-wrapper" style="width:100%; height:30px; background:#eee;">

  <img id="coment1" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style=" left:46.3%;" />
  <img id="coment2" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:26.3%;;" />
  <img id="coment3" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:36.3%;" />
  <img id="coment4" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:51%;" />
  <img id="coment4" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:51.6%;" />
  <img id="coment5" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:38%;" />
  <img id="coment6" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:21%;" />
  <img id="coment7" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:6.3%;" />
  <img id="coment8" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:12.6%;" />
  <img id="coment9" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:90%;" />
  <img id="coment10" class="comment" src="http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gravatarlogo.jpg" width="20" height="20" style="left:70%;" />

</div>

</div>
```

i am seeking something like soundcloud does on its comments system.

I am really stuck in this, and seeking for a light weight and simple solution that can work dymanically because comment id's will be coming from database and i wont be able write manual id's to any js function.

I want when this class "jp-play-bar" reach the start of the image in the bottom it ads class "active" to the image and as it reaches the end of the image it removes the active class

Thanks in advance

here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/22623/)**

Comment: Hi! Before being able to provide an answer, you need to provide some code that you have tried. This is not a code writing service so if you haven't given it a try yourself I recommend you do some more reason, give it an attempt and if that doesn't work you can come back **with your code** and ask for some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use a function comparing the with of the progress bar with the left position of an image and then call this function every time the progress bar changes.
You can call this function on the event timeupdate so you are sure that the progress bar is changing:

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_2').on($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(e){
   var progress = document.querySelector('.jp-play-bar').style.width;
   highlightImg(progress);
  });
```

and now the highlightImg function:

```
function highlightImg(progress){    
  progress = parseFloat(parseFloat(''+progress).toFixed(1)); // normalize the values to be compared easily
  var imgs = $('img.comment');
  imgs.map(function (i, im)
    {   
      var img = $(im);
      var currentImgLeftPos = parseFloat(parseFloat(im.style.left).toFixed(1)); // get the left position of the current image
      console.log(progress); // logs the progress bar width
      console.log('left' ,currentImgLeftPos); // logs the left postion of the images
      img.removeClass('active'); // remove active from other images
            if (progress > currentImgLeftPos - 1 && progress < currentImgLeftPos + 3  ) { // I just added an interval where the images can be shown otherwise the effect will very quick
        img.addClass('active'); // add the class when needed
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Hope this will help. I also updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/22626/

Comment: Hi @marouen, i saw your snippet and it is 70% of the thing which i am seeking, actually this progress will be an mp3 player and i have added a new fiddle using jplayer and in that you can see "jp-play-bar" class width is incrementing on the song. i want as the jp-play-bar reaches the images below it adds the active class to the image from where the image starts and when the jp-play-bar reach the end of image it removes the class.

Comment: @HarrisJones you didn't talk about the mp3 player in your question but this can be solved too! I'll update my answer

Comment: Yea i realized that maybe my question was not asked in a better way thats why i updated the player in the fiddle and updated the question also. Thanks alot @marouen. ill be looking forward for your help.

Comment: Man!!! You are a superheroo!! just wow! it feels like dream com true! Thankyou soo very much @marouen. i dont have words to express its just amazinggg!!! :-))

Comment: No prb! glad I could help! I trust you you'll update the code to be more readable ;-)

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, one small problem i am facing, if you play at 1:48 there are two images overlapping each other, that is fine but the problem is that both are active at the same time, is it possible that first image gets active and as soon as the start of second image comes the active class shifts to second image, i understand that the first active for first image will be very very little but that is fine for me. all i need is only one time one img active. thank you

Comment: No pbm! You just have to reduce the intervall in the condition (&& progress < currentImgLeftPos +1) or « + .5 ». You habe to play in these values

Comment: but reducing the interval is effecting for all of them, i just want if incase any image is overlapping then it should just take the visible part of the first image and then as the second image gets in position it will hide the first and show the second. and this goes if there are third or fourth or how many overlapping.

Comment: If you know which images are overlapping you can give them a special classname and then set a small interval for these images and the others should keep the old interval. I have no idea if you don't know the images overlapping :-/

Comment: Yea thats the problem because its dynamic, same as soundcloud comments, people can drag anywhere and can write a comment on the mp3 and it can be overlapped with others..

Comment: you may register all the left positions of your elements and then check the difference between every two of them so you can know if they overlap and if they do the image becomes a specific class that you can add in your conditions. May be :-)

Comment: Hey Marouen, tried but couldn't get through, i'm stuck, can you please help me with one active at a time. http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/22643/

Comment: if (progress > currentImgLeftPos - 0.1 && progress < currentImgLeftPos + 0.2  )should do it. Fiddle hier: http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/22674/